# iPhone speech recognition for an iOS Application?

Tags: ios, iphone, speech-recognition

Is there any tutorial and API available for voice recognition integration with my iOS application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823693/iphone-speech-recognition-is-in-ios-sdk-available

Answer (score 1):

Dragon API is very good for this.

http://readwrite.com/2011/01/24/dragon-speech-sdk-arrives-for-android-ios

I have already used this in one of my project.

Comment: as I understand it is for free now. At least if you don't get massive user base..